# Django: CommandError: App 'zero' does not have migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I trying to [revert the migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#migrate-app-label-migrationname) of my Django application. I have five migrations which are synced with the database. I use the following command:

```
$ python manage.py migrate zero
```

This fails with the following error message:

> CommandError: App 'zero' does not have migrations (you cannot selectively sync unmigrated apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide the app label to migrate:

```
python manage.py migrate myapp zero
```